# bluetooth - tx power and rssi

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am experimenting two low energy bluetooth 4. I am getting uuid, tx power level and rss values on the android app that I downloaded.

I noticed that one of these two is sending 0 for tx power level, but the other one is sending 4 for tx power level and see different RSSI values on the android app even though I put them in the same spot. It means that the distance is same between my android phone and these two bluetooth devices. If the difference is +/- 5, I understand, but the difference is +/- 15. Is is because of the tx power level?

And oo I need to take tx power level into consideration to calculate the proximity between the BLE 4 and my android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly relate RSSI and absolute distance between BLE central and peripheral. Of course RSSI is affected by, but not only, distance. However there are other significant factors such as interference, transmittion medium, etc. If your two BLE peripherals are two different models, the values may even vary more.

RSSI fluctuating for around +-15 is very normal for BLE connections, and nearly impossible to eliminate in practical cases. So basically you cannot only rely on RSSI for calculating distance if you want the error to be less than several meters.