# ESP32 reduce BLE connection distance

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, distance, esp32

i need to connect my phone to the esp32 with BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy). But only when you are close to just 1 meters. So, how can i reduce the meters? And also if you go far away from 1 meter, it has to disconnect. I would be happy, if you answer...

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this would be very challenging to implement because you have to rely on the RSSI to approximate the distance which is not always very reliable. Have a look at these links below for more information:-

- [Things you should know about Bluetooth range](https://blog.nordicsemi.com/getconnected/things-you-should-know-about-bluetooth-range)
- [Using BLE for indoor positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57214988/using-ble-for-indoor-positioning/57266822#57266822)
- [Fundamentals of beacon ranging](https://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html)

Answer (score 0):

Connect if the RSSI more than 40 and keep updating the RSSI for 2 seconds, get the average if it's more than -30 then you're too close to the device.